# White cloud of foam while fermenting tepache

Tags: yeast, fermentation, foam

I have lately tried to ferment tepache, for the firs time. The first stage went well, after three days there were white bubbles, it tasted less sugary and a bit yeasty. When I bottled it for the second fermentation, with no air flowing in, after 12 hours I came back to see this cloud of white foam. I am wondering what it might be.

Comment: Is there any reason to think that it's anything other than carbon dioxide + sugar?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share a picture of what this foam looks like?

If you are sure that the bottling is tight and there is no air seeping in, then it is most likely just carbon dioxide that is rising up the surface and creating the bubbles. During second fermentation, carbon dioxide is still produced.

However, if there is a possibility of any air seeping in, then it could be kahm yeast. Nothing to worry about, you can just skim it off and the rest of your tepache will be fine.